# Selecionar opção de uma lista - via Jquery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, automatização

conseguem me ajudar?

Estou tentando preencher um formulário via web, mas estou com dificuldades com combobox.

Consigo abrir as opções do combox, mas não consigo selecionar a opção que preciso 'VA - SUSTENTAVEL'.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Está é a opção que preciso selecionar:

```
<span ng-bind-html="itemProduto.description" class="ng-binding ng-scope">VA - SUSTENTAVEL</span>
```

Alguma dica?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depois de quase uma semana quebrando a cabeça, achei a resposta!

```
$("span:contains('VA - SUSTENTAVEL')").click()
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Assumindo que você precisa pegar o valor que o usuário seleciona na combobox

Eu trocaria as tags html para **select**, adicionaria um **id** (por exemplo: id="meuId") e aninharia as opções com a tag **option**, que possue a propriedade **value**.
Então, com jquery, faria:

`var valor = $(#meuId).val();`

Comment: Olá, Pedro.
Obrigado pela resposta. No caso, estou preenchendo um formulario em uma plataforma, não um outro usuário. Estou utilizando as funções para alimentar os elementos solicitados.